# Text Characters Calculation

Tags: cognito-forms

How to calculate numbers of characters in a text box, and to make sure it is not lesser than or greater than a specific amount of numbers?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.  The first involves creating a [custom error](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/11/building-forms/advanced-validation#custom-errors) that checks the length of the string.  The second involves using the settings for a text field which includes a minimum and maximum text length for the field.

<sub>I am an Engineer on the Cognito Forms team</sub>

Comment: I don't know to do this,

Comment: What I mean was, in a multiple text box, if a text characters length is below 150, it should show error, and if it is more than 350 characters, it should show error as well, that is minimum of text required is 150 and maximum is 350.  How do I place a calculation box for the multiple text box?  Regards

Answer (score 0):

You would do show custom error when:

```
=(TextBox < 150 and TextBox > 350)
```

I believe you need to have text for the error or it won't work.

> "Please use between 150 and 350 characters."

Answer (score 0):

The error does not show when the maximum number of characters is reached.  I need a character counter that the user will see when filling out the form.